# Accessing files and images from jar files

Tags: java, javafx, jar, java-8, javafx-2

I've been running into issues when trying to accessing files and images in a jar file. The program works as expected before being made into a jar file. I have created a Resources folder used ClassLoader but still getting an error on command line when trying to run the jar file it works but not all the information shows.

The type has to be a File so that the databaseReader can read it.

**Error message**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Nicholas\IdeaProjects\MirrorMe\out\artifacts\MirrorMe_jar\MirrorMe.jar!\GeoLite2-City.mmdb (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.maxmind.db.BufferHolder.<init>(BufferHolder.java:19)
    at com.maxmind.db.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:116)
    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:35)
    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:23)
    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder.build(DatabaseReader.java:129)
    at sample.LocateMyCity.<init>(LocateMyCity.java:60)
    at sample.WeatherToday.getPersonLocationId(WeatherToday.java:102)
    at sample.WeatherToday.<init>(WeatherToday.java:126)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Full Code**

```
public class LocateMyCity {

private String myCityLocation;

private String country;

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getmyCityLocation(){
    return myCityLocation;
}

public LocateMyCity() {
    try {


        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File database = new File(classLoader.getResource("GeoLite2-City.mmdb").getFile());

        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));

        String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
        System.out.println(ip);

        // This creates the DatabaseReader object, which should be reused across
        // lookups.
        DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();

        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

        // Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
        // "country".
        CityResponse response = reader.city(ipAddress);

        City city = response.getCity();
        System.out.println(city.getName()); // 'Minneapolis'
        this.myCityLocation = city.getName();

        Country country = response.getCountry();
        System.out.println(country.getIsoCode());            // 'GB'
        this.country = country.getIsoCode();

        System.out.println(country.getName());               // 'United Kindom'

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Tracing IP E");
    }
}
}
```

[image: Inside jar file]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't create a file out of a general URL: `ClassLoader.getResource(...)` returns a URL representing the location of a resource in the place from which classes are loaded: in this case in the jar file. Note that there is no `Geolite2-City.mmdb` file on the file system in this scenario: there is just the content of that original file bundled into a jar archive. If your database can only read from an actual file, then you need to extract that and place it on the file system somewhere (temp folder or user directory, as needed).

Comment: I have added screenshot to show you it is in the jar file

Comment: Yes, sorry; in my original (now deleted) comment I had misunderstood the problem. If your database needs an actual file (not a general stream), then you need to extract it from the jar file and put it on the file system (which you can do programmatically pretty easily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your application is bundled as a jar file, the resources are no longer files but are elements in an archive (the jar file). For a desktop application, the application will typically run without extracting these elements from the archive.

If your database requires an actual file, rather than just a stream it can read from (this would particularly be the case if you needed to write to it), then you cannot use a resource in an archive and will have to use a file on the file system.

You can easily extract the resource from the archive and write its content to the local filesystem. The exact details of how you do this depend on the functionality you need. For example, if you are writing to the database as part of the application's functionality, and expect those changes to persist the next time the application is run, you would only want to extract the resource from the archive on the first run (or possibly if the user deleted the file at a later stage). Normally you would do this by placing the file in the user's home directory. You might do this, for example, with:

```
Path appDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".application-name");
Path databaseFile = appDirectory.resolve("GeoList2-City.mmdb");

if (! Files.exists(databaseFile)) {
    try {
        // create the app directory if it doesn't already exist:
        Files.createDirectories(appDirectory);

        InputSteam defaultDatabase = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
        Files.copy(defaultDatabase, databaseFile);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        // handle exception here, e.g. if application can run without db,
        // set flag indicating it must run in non-db mode
        // otherwise this is probably a fatal exception, show message and exit...
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// ...

DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(databaseFile.toFile()).build();
```

If you wanted a new database every time you ran the application, you would probably copy to a temporary file instead, deleting the file when the application exits.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking around for something like this is there documentation where you learnt this?

Comment: @user2070739 I guess I just figured this out from understanding what a jar file is (it's information sort of lost in the "I can't remember learning this" part of my brain...). Does https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html help?